# Dokku / Docker deployment of non-http nodejs app

Tags: node.js, networking, nginx, docker, dokku

My objective right now is automatize a nodejs app which use just a telnet connection to receive client data (it is embed devices which send stats and their position). What they do is just send a simple csv text line so there's no HTTP headers or HTTP protocol.

It looks like that:

```
var net = require('net');
server.on('connection', function(sock) {
    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        // data handling is here
    }
}
```

Docker uses nginx to proxy local guest port and expose it to parent machine. As I understand Nginx doesn't work well with non-http connections by default.

Is there any possibility to make it work? Is it wrong to choose Dokku for automatization in this case?